# How to log to a different file in Wildfly jboss?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, slf4j

This is how I normally perform logging in Wildfly.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class MyClass{ 
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    public function testLog(){
        logger.info("Test1 -> this will be printed in /opt/servers/jboss/standalone/log/server.log");
    }
}
```

Now because `MyClass` is quite special, it need to output to a different file.

**How do I move the log** from `/opt/servers/jboss/standalone/log/server.log` to say `/opt/servers/jboss/standalone/log/myclass.log`?

I also know that we can get the current directory of the standard log by doing the following. Then I can write it to a different file, but is this the best practice?

```
File logDir = new File(System.getProperty("jboss.server.log.dir"));
// that logDir.getAbsolutePath() will result  /opt/servers/jboss/standalone/log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [logging profile](https://docs.wildfly.org/20/Admin_Guide.html#per-deployment-logging) or create a new file handler.

To create a new file handler you could do something like the following.

```
/subsystem=logging/file-handler=my-handler:add(file={path=myclass.log, relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir}, append=true, autoflush=true)
/subsystem=logging/logger=your.package.MyClass:add(handlers=[my-handler], level=INFO, use-parent-handlers=false)
```